On incorrect outputs in arithmetic involving large digits, especially in SDG
CGAL's Segment_Delaunay_graph has confirmed that given an input with very large digits due to minute numerical calculation errors, the correct result may not be obtained, but rounding the digits for the same intent input will produce the correct result.
Is this an arithmetic problem with CGAL as a whole? Or is it a Segment_Delaunay_graph (SDG) specific problem?
As to how these problems should be addressed, one solution at this time is to compensate for the input. However, this in itself is not a fundamental solution, since we want to use the results of other calculations, such as CAD, as input, which always tends to introduce minute errors in the input. If you have a good solution, I would appreciate your advice.
Below is a specific execution case that we have tried here.
Four points are input to enclose two distant line segments. This is because we want to obtain the output cell for the line segment as a closed polygon.
void TestSDGWithError()
{
    std::vector<SDG::Point_2> vpoints;
    vpoints.push_back(SDG::Point_2(199.9999999999996, 5699.9999999999991));
    vpoints.push_back(SDG::Point_2(2199.9999999999845, 5700.0000000000009));
    vpoints.push_back(SDG::Point_2(2199.999999999985, 0));
    vpoints.push_back(SDG::Point_2(199.99999999999866, 0));

    // Insertion of a point outside the domain to
    // make the Voronoi cell of the input line segment a finite cell
    CGAL::Bbox_2 bbox(-800, -1000, 3200, 6700);

    vpoints.push_back(SDG::Point_2(bbox.xmin(), bbox.ymin()));
    vpoints.push_back(SDG::Point_2(bbox.xmax(), bbox.ymin()));
    vpoints.push_back(SDG::Point_2(bbox.xmax(), bbox.ymax()));
    vpoints.push_back(SDG::Point_2(bbox.xmin(), bbox.ymax()));

    SDG dg;
    // insert points
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vpoints.size(); i++)
        dg.insert(SDG::Site_2::construct_site_2(vpoints[i]));

    // insert segments
    dg.insert(SDG::Site_2::construct_site_2(vpoints[0], vpoints[1]));
    dg.insert(SDG::Site_2::construct_site_2(vpoints[2], vpoints[3]));

    .......
}

Comparing the case with minute numerical calculation errors and the case with rounded numerical values, a single vertex coordinate value is calculated divergently in the case with errors.
Test SDG With Error
Closed Cell Polygon:
200.000, 6700.000
200.000, 2850.000
2200.000, 2850.000
2200.000, 2850.000
2200.000, 6700.000
1200.000, 88508786079941760.000 <<< Error Vertex
Closed Cell Polygon:
...

Test SDG Without Error
Closed Cell Polygon:
200.000, 2850.000
200.000, 2850.000
2200.000, 2850.000
2200.000, 2850.000
2200.000, 6700.000
1200.000, 8200.000
200.000, 6700.000
Closed Cell Polygon:
...

The plot looks like the following. The pink line is the input SITE and the green shows the respective Cell. The correct result is on the left, and the right one contains an error and one point diverges to the upper side.
Test Case Diagram
The full test project I tried is at the link below.
https://gist.github.com/ymzkd/4b8e785d1de11526b02204a88a297dad
I would appreciate any advice you can give me. Thank you in advance.
